# Trade Reconciliation Macro

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I'm trying to write a macro that will reconcile two trade reports by putting a yellow fill on trades listed on Sheet1 that are missing from Sheet2 and vice versa. I am a beginner to VBA and have been learning as I go along. Basically the approach that I have taken has been to iterate through each row on Sheet1, creating an array for each of the main fields being compared (TradeDate, Ticker, and Quantity). These arrays contain the row numbers of every match with that field in Sheet1 that is found in Sheet2. Once the arrays are created, I would like to compare the arrays and check if the same row number is contained in each. If so, the program should move on to the next trade. If not, that row should be marked with a yellow fill on Sheet1. I keep getting run-time errors for type mismatch, any input as to why?

```
Sub Reconciliation()

Sheets("Sheet1").Select

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastRow2 As Long
Dim rowCounter As Long
Dim isZero As Long

LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
With Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    LastRow2 = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
End With
isZero = 1

'Loops through every row on Sheet 1
For rowCounter = 2 To LastRow
    Dim DateValue As String
   DateValue = ActiveSheet.Cells(8, rowCounter)

    'Search Sheet2 for TradeDate and add matched rows to DateArray
    Dim DateArray() As Long
    ReDim DateArray(0 To LastRow2)


    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("E2:E" & LastRow2), DateValue) > 0 Then
        isZero = isZero * 0

    Else
        DateArray(0) = Application.Match(DateValue, Range("E2:E" & LastRow2), 0)

        Dim i As Integer
        Dim x As Integer

        x = 1
        For i = 1 To LastRow2
         If Application.Match(DateValue, Range("E" & DateArray(x - 1) & ":E" & LastRow2), 0) = "IsError" Then
            Exit For
         Else
            DateArray(x) = Application.Match(DateValue, Range("E" & DateArray(x - 1) & ":E" & LastRow2), 0)
            x = x + 1
         End If
        Next i

    End If

    Dim tickerValue As String

    tickerValue = ActiveSheet.Cells(4, rowCounter)

    Dim TickerArray() As Long
    ReDim TickerArray(0 To LastRow2)

    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    If Application.Match(tickerValue, Range("D2:D" & LastRow2), 0) = "IsError" Then
        isZero = isZero * 0
    Else

        TickerArray(0) = Application.Match(tickerValue, Range("D2:D" & LastRow2), 0)

        Dim i1 As Integer
        Dim x1 As Integer

        x = 2
        For i1 = 1 To LastRow2
            If Application.Match(tickerValue, Range("D" & TickerArray(x1 - 1) & ":D" & LastRow2), 0) = "IsError" Then
                Exit For
            Else
                ReDim Preserve TickerArray(0 To x1)
                TickerArray(x1) = Application.Match(tickerValue, Range("D" & TickerArray(x1 - 1) & ":D" & LastRow2), 0)

                x1 = x1 + 1
            End If
        Next i1
    End If

    Dim quantityValue As Long

    quantityValue = ActiveSheet.Cells(3, rowCounter)

    Dim QuantityArray() As Long
    ReDim QuantityArray(0 To LastRow2)

    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    If Application.Match(quantityValue, Range("E2:E" & LastRow2), 0) = "N/A" Then
        isZero = isZero * 0
    Else

        QuantityArray(0) = Application.Match(quantityValue, Range("E2:E" & LastRow2), 0)

        Dim i2 As Integer
        Dim x2 As Integer

        x2 = 2
        For i2 = 1 To LastRow2
            If Application.Match(quantityValue, Range("E" & QuantityArray(x2 - 1) & ":E" & LastRow2), 0) = "IsError" Then
                Exit For
            Else
                ReDim Preserve QuantityArray(0 To x2)
                QuantityArray(x2) = Application.Match(quantityValue, Range("E" & QuantityArray(x2 - 1) & ":E" & LastRow2), 0)

                x2 = x2 + 1
            End If
        Next i2

    End If







Next rowCounter
End Sub
```

Comment: [Conditional Formatting](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Use-a-formula-to-apply-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f) with a native worksheet formula seems like a better solution from your narrative. If you have two lists of trades, are you expecting each list to have identical records in identical positions (i.e. *rows*)?

Comment: What line are you getting a type mismatch at? Have you tried using the debugging mode and inserting breakpoints in your code?

Comment: @DevinTrowbridge Sorry I didn't copy the line numbers into the code here. The type mismatch is in this line: DateArray(0) = Application.Match(DateValue, Range("E2:E" & LastRow2), 0)

Answer (score 0):

So there's quite a few problems with your code. Some of it is style, some of it is syntax.

First every place that you have a:

```
Application.Match(...)
```

It needs to have WorksheetFunction in between Application and Match so it reads:

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(...)
```

---

Second try to avoid dimensioning variables inside your loops. There's no need for it, and if you want to reset your variables after each loop then add something like a var = 0 at the end.

Move DateValue and DateArray out of the For Loop. Dim DateArray once after LastRow(2) since that's the only time you do and LastRow(2) never changes.

The same goes for TickerArray, tickerValue, QuantityArray, and quantityValue.

---

Third avoid variables with numbers in them, i.e. LastRow2. This is when you need to use either a more descriptive variable name or an Array. Instead of LastRow2 use

```
Dim LastRow(1 to 2) as Long
LastRow(1) = Sheet1.UsedRange.Rows.count
LastRow(2) = Sheet2.UsedRange.Rows.count
```

---

Fourth why are you using

```
isZero = isZero*0
```

instead of

```
isZero = 0
```

---

Fifth, don't use the select() method so much. Its slow and clunky compared to just referencing the sheet you want directly

i.e. instead of doing this

```
LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.count
With Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    LastRow2 = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.count
End With
```

do this instead

```
LastRow(1) = Sheet1.UsedRange.Rows.count
LastRow(2) = Sheet2.UsedRange.Rows.count
```

---

Sixth you don't need three separate x and i variables, you can dim them once outside of the highest For loop and reuse them for your lower For loops in the If-Else statements.

Comment: I pretty much have zero clue what I'm doing so your corrections are a tremendous help. Thank you so much!!

Comment: @A.Sarma No problem. You should try reading a style guide and try an online class on programming, e.g. codeacademy

Comment: I made the changes you suggested, but now I am getting a variable defined error on 'LastRow(1) = Sheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count' am I missing something?